# error "Cannot open include file", but it's not included in code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, initializer-list

I got the error after installing November CTP in Visual Studio 2012.
The error is in `unordered_set.hpp` of boost library. But I have not included `unordered_set` or `initializer_list` anywhere in the code. I used boost only in one file and I am sure it's not the reason.

error in unordered_set.hpp:

```
#if !defined(BOOST_NO_0X_HDR_INITIALIZER_LIST)
#include <initializer_list>  //error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'initializer_list': No such file or directory d:\boost\unordered\unordered_set.hpp
#endif
```

EDIT:

I uninstalled November CTP after, but still got the same error.

Comment: use "show includes" option to see what happens

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is \_CPPLIB\_VER defined and is it modifiable in visual studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296629/where-is-cpplib-ver-defined-and-is-it-modifiable-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

`C++11` is enabled by default in VS2012.
From `boost` headers

```
#if !defined(BOOST_NO_0X_HDR_INITIALIZER_LIST)
#include <initializer_list>
#endif
```

You may try to define `BOOST_NO_0X_HDR_INITIALIZER_LIST`, or find `initializer_list` header location.

```
// config/suffix.hpp
#if defined(BOOST_NO_INITIALIZER_LISTS) && !defined(BOOST_NO_0X_HDR_INITIALIZER_LIST)
#  define BOOST_NO_0X_HDR_INITIALIZER_LIST
#endif

// config/compilers/visualc.hpp
#if _MSC_VER <= 1500  || !defined(BOOST_STRICT_CONFIG) // 1500 == VC++ 9.0
#  define BOOST_NO_INITIALIZER_LISTS
#endif
```

`BOOST_STRICT_CONFIG` may be commented in `config/user.hpp`.

However, it looks like you have no modern Visual C++ headers, that is strange since you have VS2012 (`initializer_list` header will be added in VS2010 actually).

Comment: @zwx look like it's unreal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536029/disabling-c0x-features-in-vc-2010

Comment: It's weird. I uninstalled the November CTP but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Today had the same issue, I found that installing the November CTP is not enough, you need to change the platform toolset under project configuration to `Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP (v120_CTP_Nov2012)` to actually use the new features, hope this helps anyone.