# Disabling C++11 features on VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to disable C++11 features on VS2012? My code isn't ready for that yet and I'd like not to introduce further confusion

Comment: Does the approach mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3536297/519383) in the comment help (i.e. using VS2008 compiler through VS2012)?

Comment: I would also like to know if it's possible on VS2010, sorry to hijack.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536029/disabling-c0x-features-in-vc-2010

Comment: You are at least two years late then

Comment: If your code "isn't ready for that" then it must be a serious hack.  There's a legitimate need to get warned about use of C++11, if the code needs to also compile on other compilers.  But disabling C++11?  No need.

Comment: Actually a rather good question could be: "How to specify C++ compatibility level for Microsoft C++ compiler"

Comment: I cannot find the answer so I opened this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753568/is-there-a-way-to-specify-c-compatibility-level-for-microsoft-c-compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Visual C++ 2015 Update 3, it is now possible to specify a language version for language behavior (apparently it doesn't affect just conformance checking):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/

Unfortunately the only options are "C++14" (not exact, it includes post-C++14 features which had previously shipped) and "C++ Latest" (C++14 plus partial implementation of C++17 and proposals, but not "experimental" features)

The corresponding command line switches are:

- `/std:c++14`
- `/std:c++latest`

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project -> Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset -> Visual Studio 2010

This will compile the project with the Visual Studio 2010 compiler.

Comment: But, VS2010 also has limited c++11.

Comment: and you need to have the compiler of VS'10 setup on your system. It'snt include with VS'12

Comment: @Waldermort There is VS2008 as well which doesn't have any C++11

Comment: @Caesar I think I'm gonna have to throw in the towel and upgrade. I just hope the VS2010 annoyances have been fixed.

Comment: What beats me is why, as the compiler gets better and better and the IDE gets more and more bloat, they give you an option to combine the worst of both -- new IDE+old compiler -- and not the other way around.  Or has someone written a targetting pack for VC++ 2010 to run the 2012 compiler?

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not saying that it is the greatest thing in the world, I'm saying it is option to the question.

Comment: While this is a bit off topic for the question it is useful to know this option as some projects on Visual Studio 2012 may have this toggled and confuse users of why they cant use c++ 11 features.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can disable C++11 features on the Visual C++ compiler.  The `/Tc` compiler option will cause errors for C++11 syntax.

Unfortunately, C++03 and C++98 will be collateral damage.  All that is left will be C89, plus a few Microsoft extensions like support for `//single line comments`.

Comment: I think it's important to clarify more that Tc will downgrade to C. It's not just you loose some C++, but you loose C++ all together.

Comment: @Csaba: Yes, that's right.  Did my second paragraph mean something else to you?

Comment: @JohnDibling: Probably because I didn't answer the question the OP obviously meant.  But I don't think "how can I run Visual C++ 2012 in C++03 mode?" has any answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt I didn't downvote. I admit, that "All that is left will be C89" does say that you left with C only. But some people might overlook that.

Comment: Wording such as "Yes, you can disable C++11 features, but only by disabling *all* C++ features" may have avoided the down-votes.  But, I like it like it is.... :)