# Is there a way to specify C++ compatibility level for Microsoft C++ compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, compatibility

`/Tc` compiler option resort only to `C`, but is there any way to specify the exact compatibility level for the Microsoft `C++` compiler? Like `C++11`, `C++03`, `C++98`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Visual C++ 2015 Update 3, it is now possible to specify a language version for language behavior (apparently it doesn't affect just conformance checking):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/

Unfortunately the only options are "C++14" (not exact, it includes post-C++14 features which had previously shipped) and "C++ Latest" (C++14 plus partial implementation of C++17 and proposals, but not "experimental" features).  There still are no options for enabling/disabling earlier versions of the language (C++98 / C++03 / C++11 as mentioned in the question)

The corresponding command line switches are:

- `/std:c++14`
- `/std:c++latest`

Comment: Good to know enhancement!

Answer (score 2):

No, the Microsoft compiler doesn't provide configurable compatibility. It is what it is.

Comment: Seems like it. Do you any article where this is stated explicitly, or we conclude the answer using our knowledge and lack of compiler options?

Comment: No, just experience and lack of compiler options.

Comment: Ok, let's mark it. Let me know if anyone has an objection. BTW, GCC has an `-std` switch: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2//gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options which can provide a bunch of "dialects".