# Compiling old C++ code on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, backwards-compatibility

I'm trying to compile [OpenBabel 2.3.2](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page) on Visual Studio 2013. The compilation fails miserably, mostly due to the fact that OpenBabel was developed in 2009, and Visual Studio 2013 has some C++11 related [breaking changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx) .

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio 2013 to compile the code in C+09 mode, or something similar? I'd much rather *not* install Visual Studio 2012 or 2010 and compile OpenBabel with that, if at all possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling C++11 features on VS2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752246/disabling-c11-features-on-vs2012)

Comment: What compiler did it target at the time of development?

Comment: A lot of the issues listed on the MS site are conformance issues. If you do not have to use VS2013, an earlier VS version may offer more compatibility with the code base.

Comment: It's a cross-platform project, they probably targeted one GCC or another. It should compile on Visual Studio 2010 properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change the Platform Tool set in order to do this.
Please find following links which contain extra details on it.

[Visual Studio 2013 msvcr120 to msvcr100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706421/visual-studio-2013-msvcr120-to-msvcr100)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx

Comment: ...assuming you have earlier versions installed.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing - installed Visual Studio 2010, changed the Platform Toolset in the Visual Studio 2013 project to 2010 and compiled. It worked.