# Lowering a Visual C++ 2010 framework target

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I've browsed around StackOverflow but couldn't find any pratical solution to something that would seem to have such an easy solution: I had a bunch of .Net projects that were developed back in VS2005 or VS2008 and I imported them into VS2010. One of them is a C++ project, which currently targets framework 4.0 (not by my choice). One of our clients is having a problem running this application, the lack of a MSVCP100D.dll. I checked this thread [what is MSVCP100D.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580685/what-is-msvcp100d-dll) and the most accepted answer is simple: having the client install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package. However, the client is stubborn enough not to install it and I know for a fact that they have Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable installed. So, if I'm correct in my conclusions and MSVCP100D.dll is new to VS2010, I could just target a previous framework version, rebuild the project in VS2010 and I'd be good to go. The problem is: how do I chance a VC++ target framework? I could find several guidelines to change C# and VB projects, but none about VC++. Any pointers?

Edit: To you guys who suggested that I compile it in Release mode: I am! It's been pointed out that the "D" stands for debug, which is rather strange.

Comment: You did see that that is the debug version of the library (which **can not** be [legally] redistributed)?

Comment: Have you tried compiling your program in *release* mode? MSVCP100D.DLL is the *debug* build of the runtime library. This is explained in the accepted answer of the question you linked to.

Comment: Well, I changed Platform Toolset, made sure I was compiling in Release mode (although I was pretty sure before) and sent it away (it's kinda though to test lacking dependencies when you have everything installed in your machine). I'll get back as soon as I have some feedback from support department

Comment: Rather than sending it anywhere to be tested, use something like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to verify that you don't have any references to debug DLLs before troubling anybody else with it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are using the debug version of the runtime (That's the "D"). Did you try compiling with a non-debug version?

Another possibility to consider would be to statically link with the runtime library. Your program will be larger, but will not have the DLL dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the information on the "D", although I'm pretty sure I compiled it in release mode. Also, I'm not very big on statically linking a .dll as it might cause somewhat of a "chain-dependency reaction" ^^

Answer (score 1):

Go into the project's properties.

On the lefthand side, go into **Configuration Properties** > **General**.

Look at the **Platform Toolset** value.  Select *v90* from the drop down list to target 2008.

See here for further details:
[Visual C++ 2010 compatibility with VC 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435213/visual-c-2010-compatibility-with-vc-2008)

See here for yet even more details:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx

[image]

Also as Dark Falcon mentions, that's the debug version of the runtime.